# Firefox crashes when HUD is opened

Tags: unity, firefox, hud

Every time I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> from Firefox to open the HUD, Firefox crashes.

What do I have to do?

Comment: [Let me guess. You have firebug extension installed.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/globalmenu-extension/+bug/1025011)

Comment: Yes you're right. Is it the fault of firebug? Do I have to reinstall it or is there another way?

Comment: It apparently is a bug in firebug. If you want to not have Firefox crash, either uninstall firebug or don't use HUD. :-)

Comment: Ok, my solution is, i deactivated firebug and when i need it i'll activate it and not use the HUD. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Happy to help. This question will now be closed as off-topic because bugs (and bug reports by extension) are off-topic to the site. Thanks for visiting the site.

Comment: A link to the bug report would be useful.